# Category Both side

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

[I want to make category widget  like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQRdD.png)

I want to create a widget like this picture. I a widget created. But My all categories are show down but I want to show them side by side.

here is my Dynamic php code:

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ul class="arrow">
                    <?php
                        $args = array(
                          'orderby' => 'name',
                          'parent' => 0,
                            'hide_empty'    =>  0
                          );
                        $categories = get_categories( $args );
                        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                            echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And Here is my Output HTML code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="arrow">
      <li><a href="">bootstrap</a></li>
      <li><a href="">csss</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Habi Jabi</a></li>
      <li><a href="">HTCSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">html</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Ki Kpi</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Laravel</a></li>
      <li><a href="">lol</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Lolop</a></li>
      <li><a href="">new</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Php</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Uncategorized</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>                </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to create like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="arrow">
      <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="arrow">
      <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Magento</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i write my code? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code should look like this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent' => 0,
        'hide_empty'    =>  0
    );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    $split = sizeof( $categories ) / 2;
    foreach ( $categories as $index => $category ) {
        if( $index == $split ) {
            echo '</ul></div><div class="col-sm-6"><ul class="arrow"></ul></div>';
        }
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

You may need to adjust the $split variable by subtracting 1 to accommodate the fact that size of will give the number of elements in the $categories array, but $index (in the foreach loop) will start at 0.